# How do I find mismatches in two tables?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I have a database where I'm trying to find inconsistencies across two tables.  I'm new to SQL and would like some help.  The other questions I've looked up are confusing and too convoluted for what I'm trying to do.

Here's the situation:  I have two tables where an ID is listed. I need to find the rows in each table for which there is no match in the other table.  For example, table 1 would have a list of 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, and 10.  Table 2 would have a list of 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, and 10.I need to run a query to find the entries for 3, 6, and 9, since these are the entries that only appear in one of the two tables.

In my situation, it would be thousands of numbers. So, how would I go about finding the mismatches?

Comment: Are the ID's Primary Keys to the table, or are they stored values within the table itself? Also are you referencing MSSQL? ORACLE? MySQL?

Comment: I don't know what a primary key is, so I can't answer that.  I'm using phpMyAdmin via the web.

Comment: Hmm, are you using MySQL?

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin

Comment: Okay, I am going to make the assumption that you are using MySQL and no Microsoft SQL Server etc..

Comment: One of the other guys said it sounds like it's MySQL.

Comment: It's your database. You really ought to be the one that knows what you are using.

Comment: @Emanu; what does `select @@version;` show?

Comment: @ Martin Smith.  As I said in the post, I'm new to SQL.  Please provide solutions, not condescending banter.

@ypercubeᵀᴹ, that returns the result of 10.1.13-MariaDB

Comment: It's not condescending in any way. If you ask for help in this site, you should at least know what DBMS you are using.

Comment: @ypercube™ It is in the sense that stating that without offering someone the knowledge of how to find that information, such as you did after he said that, it stands alone as such a comment.  Anyway, looking for updates for the MariaDB issue :-(

Comment: @Emanu I understand. But the site is for professional help (from the Help section: *"What topics can I ask about here? dba.se is for those needing expert answers to **advanced** database-related questions concerning traditional SQL RDBMS and NoSQL alternatives."* If someone asks questions related to how to drive/turn/stop a truck, you assume they know what type/brand of truck it is even if they don't have a licence ;)

Comment: Thanks for the attempts at helping me solve this, but I need to run to work for now.  I'll try again later.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL (and the derivative) MariaDB have not implemented `FULL JOIN`. So you need either 2 queries or a `UNION` of 2 `NOT EXISTS` subqueries.

To find the not matched IDs using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.id, 'IDs_in_t1_but_not_in_t2' AS mismatch
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM table2 AS t2
        WHERE t2.id = t1.id
      ) 
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.id, 'IDs_in_t2_but_not_in_t1'
FROM table1 AS t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM table1 AS t1
        WHERE t1.id = t2.id
      ) ;
```

or using `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`:

```
SELECT t1.id, 'IDs_in_t1_but_not_in_t2' AS mismatch
FROM table1 AS t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
  ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.id, 'IDs_in_t2_but_not_in_t1'
FROM table1 AS t2
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS t1
  ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id IS NULL ;
```

Comment: ypercube, here's what I got from your answer:

Static analysis:

3 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "NOT" at position 78)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "EXISTS" at position 82)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 96)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT t1.id, 'IDs_in_t1_but_not_in_t2' AS mismatch FROM table1 AS t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( LIMIT 0, 25

Comment: My query does not have any `LIMIT 0, 25`. This must have been added by PHPMySQLAdmin or whatever you use to run the queries. Check their documentation on how to remove that from the query.

Comment: MariaDB apparently doesn't recognize EXISTS

Comment: MariaDB has `EXISTS` just fine. It's the GUI tool you use that breaks things.

Comment: Agree'd, MariaDB does have `EXISTS`

Comment: How about replacing `NOT EXISTS` with NOT IN (Subselect)?

Comment: Or with LEFT JOIN + IS NULL. Although it's still madness that the query doesn't appear to be sent to the server as is (assuming there's no error on the OP's side).

Comment: I could write the LEFT JOIN / IS NULL version. But @Emanu, it's better to fix your phpmyAdmin. See this bug report: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11558 Seems like you need to update your phpmyadmin to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

The question was only tagged sql when I answered. The following answer is valid for DBMS that support "Full outer join", such as SQL Server.

What you can use is a "full outer join". This join type will keep all values from the left table and all from the right table, and match those that match.

```
select t1.id, t2.id 
from t1 
full outer join t2 
on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id is null or t2.id is null
```

So (with simple example data):

```
create table #t1 (id int, val nvarchar(10))
create table #t2 (id int, val nvarchar(10))

insert into #t1 VALUES (1, 'one')
insert into #t1 VALUES (2, 'two')

insert into #t2 VALUES (2, 'two')
insert into #t2 VALUES (3, 'three')

select #t1.*, #t2.*
from #t1 
full outer join #t2 
on #t1.id = #t2.id
```

will yield the table

```
id   val  id   val
1    one  NULL NULL
2    two  2    two
NULL NULL 3    three
```

and

```
delete #t1
from #t1 
full outer join #t2 
on #t1.id = #t2.id
where #t2.id is null
```

will delete those entries from #t1 where there is no match in #t2

Comment: Thanks.  I used your script, but after entering it, I get an error on line 3 stating "Unrecognized keyword. (near outer)"

Comment: You need to replace the t1 and t2 alias with your actual database aliases.
Send us your actual table names and column name for the ID and we can provide you code that you can copy and paste from.

Comment: I did.  Here's the modded script you sent:

Comment: select forest.GeoDataID, forest_patch.GeoDataID 
from forest 
full outer join forest_patch 
on forest.GeoDataID = forest_patch.GeoDataID
where forest.GeoDataID is null or forest_patch.GeoDataID is null

Comment: Oops, let me repost with shift+enter:

select forest.GeoDataID, forest_patch.GeoDataID 
from forest 
full outer join forest_patch 
on forest.GeoDataID = forest_patch.GeoDataID
where forest.GeoDataID is null or forest_patch.GeoDataID is null

Comment: It's not letting me add lines, only letting me comment in bulk

Comment: @Emanu Looks like you are using MySQL? That doesn't support `full outer join`

Comment: So, how do I do this?

Comment: Down vote, question as only tagged SQL when I answered

Comment: @Paparazzi I just updated the question and tagged it with MariaDB to help clarify further post

Comment: I think this was indeed a perfectly honest attempt at an answer. However, @Paparazzi, now that the platform is known, and it's one that doesn't support full joins, I think your suggestion has simply become irrelevant to the question, which works for me as an explanation for the downvote. The situation itself (answer becoming irrelevant after more details are revealed) has happened to me many times, and sometimes I correct the answer and other times I delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the attempts at helping me solve this, but I need to run to work for now.  I'll try again later.

Comment: Why did this answer get 2 down votes? It was posted before the OP mentioned any DBMS and it does answer the question ...